# Does Gmail calculate email storage per plus sign or alias address?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

With Gmail you can arrange additional address aliases by appending `+` and any arbitrary string to your original login.

Example:

- original account: johndoe@gmail.com
- sample aliases: johndoe+subscriptions@gmail.com, johndoe+work@gmail.com, etc.

Do messages sent to an alias address add up to the original account's storage limit,
or by working with aliases can one get some additional storage, say: 2GB per alias?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alias = mirror of the original or main email address. Therefore the disk space is shared between the two.

Good explanation over [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/12614735).

> An alias is essentially just a nickname for a mail account. The alias itself has no mailbox and all mail sent to it will be delivered to the mailbox it is mapped to.